# Store List of Objects into a column and trigger a Mail - C#, SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Trying to store list of users (objects) into the database and trigger a Mail to the recipient with the same list. I am using MSSQL and C# for my project. Below code is running successfully if I intend to save just one user. But I am having issues to save a list of users. I am requesting to help me with some ideas on how to achieve the following. Thank you.

```
public class ExportService{
public string SendImportStatus(List<Import> users)
        {
            Let<Notification>().SaveListToSendEmail(users);
            return null;
        }
}

public class Notification{
public void SaveListToSendEmail(List<Import> users)
        {
            if (IsNullOrEmpty(users))
            {
                return;
            }
            SendEmailBody(actedBy, users);
        }
}

 private void SendEmailBody(List<Import> users)
        {
            var getManagers = Let<User>().GetAll();
            var type = NotificationType.ModuleImport;
            var recipientEmails = getManagers .Select(model => model.Email);
            var emailToList = string.Join(";", recipientEmails);
            var template = Let<EmailTemplate>().GetItemByCode(EnumHelper.GetDescription(type));

            var fileName = users.Select(x => x.FileName).First();
            var notification = new NotificationM()
            {
                Type = type,
                To = emailToList
            };

            notification.Value = new
            {
                ModuleCode = fileName,
                list = users //[{"Id":"A","Status":"Success},{"Id":"B","Status":"Fail"},..]
            };

            var recipient = BuildRecipient(template, notification);
            Let<Recipient>().Save(recipient, actedBy);
        }
}
```

Building the Recipient with above data.

```
protected RecipientDM BuildRecipient(EmailTemplateDM template, NotificationM notificationM)
        {
            var subject = StringHelper.Fill(template.GetSubject(), notificationM.Value);
            var body = StringHelper.Fill(template.GetContent(), notificationM.Value);

            return BuildRecipient(notificationM.Id, notificationM.Type, recipient =>
            {
                recipient.To = notificationM.To;
                recipient.Cc = notificationM.Cc;
                recipient.Bcc = notificationM.Bcc;
                recipient.Subject = subject;
                recipient.Body = body;
            });
        }
```

String Helper Class, for now its able to store the value of `ModuleCode` into the database. But I am not able to figure out how to save the list.

```
public static string Fill(object value)
        {
            var pairs = ConvertHelper.ToPairs(value);
            foreach (var key in pairs.Keys)
            {
                var text = pairs[key] == null ? string.Empty : pairs[key].ToString();
                template = Regex.Replace(template, $"##{key}##".Trim(), text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            }

            return template;
        }
```

Database column `Body` has this hard coded where `##ModuleCode##` and `##list##` will get replaced.

```
'<p>Dear Manager(s), <br /> <br />Module - ##ModuleCode## -  is imported.<br /><br /><h3>Please find More Details below</h3><br />
  <table><tr><td>##list##<td></tr></table>
```

I am expecting the following email result.

```
  Dear Manager(s), 

  Module - abc  is imported

  Please find more details below.
  
 ---------------
 | A | Success |
 | B | Failure |
 ---------------
```

Comment: *"I am having issues to save a list of users"* - What specific "issues" are you having?  If you're able to successfully save one record, what's stopping you from repeating that operation?

Comment: @David I get ```<table><tr><td> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[App.BLL.Notification+SendEmail]```</td</tr></table> while saving it to my database.

Comment: Then presumably you are trying to treat an entire list as a single record where you should instead probably be looping over the list and handling individual records.

Comment: @David Yes I understand you, but I am still a bit confused. Your kind help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: The code shown in the question is very disjointed and full of typos, so there isn't much I can give you for specific guidance.  Reduce the problem to just where you use the `List` of records.  Where even is that in the code?  I don't see a `List` anywhere?  Though I do see severl uses of `object`, which implies that you're not relying on types properly at all.  But presumably *somewhere* in your code you have a `List` of records, and you are passing that entire `List` to this process of yours.  Instead, write a loop to iterate over that `List` and pass *each object* to this process of yours.

Comment: @David I have added all the codes for your reference. Please help.